# WinApi: WSASend и GetQueuedCompletionStatus

Tags: c++, c, winsock, winsock2

Собственно вот такой вопрос:

Есть две функции: WSASend и GetQueuedCompletionStatus.
Обе функции одним из параметров принимают структуру WSAOVERLAPPED, в которую что то там записывают.

В случае с WSASend-GetQueuedCompletionStatus в WSAOVERLAPPED идет запись в параметр WSAOVERLAPPED.InternalHigh — то кол-во байт, которое якобы отправлено на данный момент функцией WSASend.

И вот вопрос:

1)Получается, что приходится для одной и той же операции Send создавать две структуру и два раза ее передавать, но, если WSASend используется совместно с портами завершения, то информацию пользователь же получает из очереди порта завершения посредством функции GetQueuedCompletionStatus куда я и передаю дублированную структуру WSAOVERLAPPED. Зачем же тогда две структуры передавать ?

2)И второй вопрос: у функции GetQueuedCompletionStatus — второй параметр это:

> Указатель на переменную, которая получает количество байтов,
> переданных в завершенной операции ввода-вывода.

и соответственно, как уже писал выше 4ый параметр — это структура WSAOVERLAPPED, которая так в один из своих полей получает — "количество байтов, переданных в завершенной операции ввода-вывода.".
Зачем тогда нужен второй параметр ? Или зачем тогда вообще передавать WSAOVERLAPPED, если есть второй параметр, куда GetQueuedCompletionStatus и так запишет нужное кол-во байт ?

Comment: Что-то вы тут напридумывали. *куда я и передаю дублированную структуру WSAOVERLAPPED* - в документации к GetQueuedCompletionStatus прямо сказано, что передавать необходимо указатель на указатель в который функция запишет указатель на структуру OVERLAPPED, использованную при старте асинхронной операции, это выходной параметр и передавать туда структуру вы никак не можете.

Comment: user7860670, да, прошу прощения некорректно составил вопрос. А, тогда правильно ли я понимаю, что GetQueuedCompletionStatus поместит в этот указатель адрес той структуры WSAOVERLAPPED, которую я указывал для WSASend ?

Comment: Да, там будет указатель именно на структуру, использованную при страте.

Comment: user7860670, а зачем тогда нужен второй параметр GetQueuedCompletionStatus, которая так же получает информацию о отправленных/полученных байтов ?

Comment: Там будут информация о количестве байт, которые должна передать операция до полного завершения.

Comment: @user7860670, насколько я понимаю вы не правы, это именно информация о том, сколько байт уже предано, ведь я достал ее из очереди порта ЗАВЕРШЕНИЯ и она полностью совпадает со значением заполненным в WSAOVERLAPPED.InternalHigh.

Comment: WSASend и GetQueuedCompletionStatus - это абсолютно разные функции, которые явно между собой не связаны. (Их надо как-то связать, затрудняюсь сказать как), Учитывая, что  WSASend может работать асинхронно -  она использует свой WSAOVERLAPPED для этого, GetQueuedCompletionStatus тоже может работать асинхронно, у неё будет свой собственный OVERLAPPED если вызов асинхронный, и эти два "OVERLAPPED" не желательно смешивать, смешение даст UB или сбой.

Comment: А что именно будет помещено в OVERLAPPED первой и второй - думаю тут вам не скажут. Тем более что рабочий пример вы не предоставили, а быстро найти это не получается.